# Replacing an executable path with variable?

Tags: bash, unix

Is it possible to replace the path to an executable with a variable?

```
CFBuildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildNumber" $buildPlist)
```

This is what I want to do, but I think I am messing the syntax up

```
buddyPath = /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
CFBuildNumber=$($buddyPath -c "Print CFBuildNumber" $buildPlist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing a command whose name is in a variable should work fine, but you can't set a variable that way. Use

```
buddyPath=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
```

without spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close, too used to formatting my code in Xcode, very much appreciated.